# How to select specific data from a REST API using JavaScript and HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hello I am trying to create a simple javascript that pulls data from a REST API. I am looking to only pull 1 data set within the API or json list of items.

Where as I only need the "last" data set to be included within the population not everything else.

I have tried using a different method of retriving the last price data set via curl however the resource blocks requests in php. Thus I need to do this with javascript.

```
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = (ourRequest.responseText);
```

I have tried changing this section to be

```
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = (ourRequest.responseText.last);
```

and a few other variables however returned no success on the output.

Below is the js code that I have made so far however it shows all the API information on the page where I only need to select 1 part of the information.

```
<p id="output"></p>

<script>
var burl = "https://api.idex.market/returnTicker?market=ETH_STASH";
var url = burl;
var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
ourRequest.open('GET',url,true);
ourRequest.onload = function(){

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = (ourRequest.responseText);
}
ourRequest.send();
</script>
```

I am expecting to have only 0.00000001512001 as the result being the "last" data set.

and the output is the following:

{"last":"0.00000001512001","high":"0.00000015","low":"0.00000001512001","lowestAsk":"0.00000058999999999","highestBid":"0.00000001","percentChange":"-89.91999333","baseVolume":"0.965950839330223243","quoteVolume":"24272447.879302712135495139"}

You can test and edit it here to try: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FYUDV3ZFYNA9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

`document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = (ourRequest.responseText);`

to

`document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = (JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText).last);`

Full working solution:

```
<script>
var burl = "https://api.idex.market/returnTicker?market=ETH_STASH";
var url = burl;
var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
ourRequest.open('GET',url,true);
ourRequest.onload = function(){
   document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText).last;
}
ourRequest.send();
</script>
```

Comment: This results in the following result "undefined"

Comment: I've edited the answer - you need to parse the response to JSON before you can use it

Comment: I also have tried the updated code however does not work. Can you try with the supplied link in the question description to help me better..

Comment: I've updated again above and in the w3schools example. I moved the `.last` outside of the JSON.parse method

Comment: Yes it does, I apologize, I had the old test from the previous answer. Your method is correct!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186152/discussion-between-rastalamm-and-od-applications).

Answer (score 0):

Convert the responseText to a valid JavaScript Object using

```
let returned_data = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
```

Then access the last property as

```
 last = returned_data['last'];
```

## Editted

```
<script>
var burl = "https://api.idex.market/returnTicker?market=ETH_STASH";
var url = burl;
var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
ourRequest.open('GET',url,true);
ourRequest.onload = function(){
let returned_data = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
let last = returned_data['last'];
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = last;
}
ourRequest.send();
</script>
```

Comment: I tried your method however it did not return any data at all. This is the code 
'code'
    <p id="output"></p>
    
    <script>
    var burl = "https://api.idex.market/returnTicker?market=ETH_STASH";
    var url = burl;
    var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ourRequest.open('GET',url,true);
    ourRequest.onload = function(){

    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = (ourRequest.responseText);
    }
    
    let returned_data = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
    
    last = returned_data['last'];
    
    ourRequest.send();
    </script> 'code'

Comment: You got it wrong. I meant, ourRequest.onload = function(){
let returned_data = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText); let last = returned_data['last']; document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = last;
}

Comment: Maybe you can use the link in the description to test and save the code so I can understand what you mean, because I added the code, but I think it was in the wrong place.